# Does mockito check/match argument values in verify

Tags: scala, mockito

In this test case, I want to check that a function is called a specific no. of times with specific values

```scala
    "add tag information in supported tags" in {
          val servicesTestEnv = new ServicesTestEnv(components = components)
    
          val questionTransactionDBService = new QuestionsTransactionDatabaseService(
            servicesTestEnv.mockAnswersTransactionRepository,
            servicesTestEnv.mockPartitionsOfATagTransactionRepository,
            servicesTestEnv.mockPracticeQuestionsTagsTransactionRepository,
            servicesTestEnv.mockPracticeQuestionsTransactionRepository,
            servicesTestEnv.mockSupportedTagsTransactionRepository,
            servicesTestEnv.mockUserProfileAndPortfolioTransactionRepository,
            servicesTestEnv.mockQuestionsCreatedByUserRepo,
            servicesTestEnv.mockTransactionService,
            servicesTestEnv.mockPartitionsOfATagRepository,
            servicesTestEnv.mockHelperMethods
          )
          when(servicesTestEnv.mockTransactionService.start)
            .thenReturn(servicesTestEnv.mockDistributedTransaction)
    
          doNothing().when(servicesTestEnv.mockPracticeQuestionsTransactionRepository).add(ArgumentMatchers.any[DistributedTransaction],ArgumentMatchers.any[PracticeQuestion],ArgumentMatchers.any[MutationCondition])
          doNothing().when(servicesTestEnv.mockPracticeQuestionsTagsTransactionRepository).add(ArgumentMatchers.any[DistributedTransaction],ArgumentMatchers.any[PracticeQuestionTag],ArgumentMatchers.any[MutationCondition])
          when(servicesTestEnv.mockPartitionsOfATagTransactionRepository.get(ArgumentMatchers.any[DistributedTransaction],ArgumentMatchers.any[TagPartitionKeys]))
            .thenReturn(Right(servicesTestEnv.questionTestEnv.tagPartitions))
          doNothing().when(servicesTestEnv.mockPartitionsOfATagTransactionRepository).add(ArgumentMatchers.any[DistributedTransaction],ArgumentMatchers.any[TagPartitions],ArgumentMatchers.any[MutationCondition])
          doNothing().when(servicesTestEnv.mockQuestionsCreatedByUserRepo).add(ArgumentMatchers.any[DistributedTransaction],ArgumentMatchers.any[QuestionsCreatedByAUserForATag],ArgumentMatchers.any[MutationCondition])
          when(servicesTestEnv.mockUserProfileAndPortfolioTransactionRepository.get(ArgumentMatchers.any[DistributedTransaction],ArgumentMatchers.any[ExternalUserProfileKeys]))
            .thenReturn(Right(servicesTestEnv.externalUserProfileWithTags))
          doNothing().when(servicesTestEnv.mockUserProfileAndPortfolioTransactionRepository).update(ArgumentMatchers.any[DistributedTransaction],ArgumentMatchers.any[ExternalUserProfile])
          doNothing().when(servicesTestEnv.mockDistributedTransaction).commit()
          when(servicesTestEnv.mockSupportedTagsTransactionRepository.get(ArgumentMatchers.any[DistributedTransaction],ArgumentMatchers.any[SupportedTagsKeys]))
            .thenReturn(Left(SupportedTagNotFoundException()))
          val supportedTagInfo = SupportedTag("coding","javascript1","empty")
          logger.trace(s"will compare with ${supportedTagInfo}")
          val result = questionTransactionDBService.newQuestion(servicesTestEnv.questionTestEnv.practiceQuestion,servicesTestEnv.questionTestEnv.practiceQuestionTag,servicesTestEnv.user)
          verify(servicesTestEnv.mockSupportedTagsTransactionRepository,times(0))
            .add(servicesTestEnv.mockDistributedTransaction,supportedTagInfo)
        }
```

If I change the value of `supportedTagInfo` to `val supportedTagInfo = SupportedTag("coding","javascript-something else","empty")`, the test case still passes.

In the traces,I can see that in both times the tag `coding-javascript-empty` was used. This value comes from `servicesTestEnv.questionTestEnv.practiceQuestionTag` which is common for both test cases and is supplied at

```scala
val result = questionTransactionDBService.newQuestion(servicesTestEnv.questionTestEnv.practiceQuestion,servicesTestEnv.questionTestEnv.practiceQuestionTag,servicesTestEnv.user)
```

`TRACE - saving coding-javascript-empty in supported tag information`

Am I doing something wrong or does Mockito not check the argument values?

UPDATE
I tried using `ArgumentCaptor` in `Scala` but am struggling.

I have created `mock` of the class as

```scala
val mockSupportedTagsTransactionRepository = mock(classOf[SupportedTagsTransactionRepository])
```

I am calling `add` method of the mock. Its signature is

```scala
def add(transaction:DistributedTransaction,supportedTag:SupportedTag,mutationCondition:MutationCondition = new PutIfNotExists()) = {...}
```

I call `get` and `add` methods of the above mock. I have defined their behaviour as

```scala
          when(servicesTestEnv.mockSupportedTagsTransactionRepository.get(ArgumentMatchers.any[DistributedTransaction],ArgumentMatchers.any[SupportedTagsKeys]))
            .thenReturn(Left(SupportedTagNotFoundException()))
```

Then I create the required `ArgumentCaptor`

```scala
       val argumentCaptor2 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[SupportedTag])
       val argumentCaptor3 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[MutationCondition])
```

and then invoke the function under test

```scala
verify(servicesTestEnv.mockSupportedTagsTransactionRepository ,times(1))
            .add(argumentCaptor1.capture(),argumentCaptor2.capture(),argumentCaptor3.capture())
          logger.trace(s"capture 1 ${argumentCaptor1.getAllValues}")
          logger.trace(s"capture 2 ${argumentCaptor2.getAllValues}")
          logger.trace(s"capture 3 ${argumentCaptor3.getAllValues}")
```

Then I check the result

```scala
val argumentsInvoked = argumentCaptor2.getAllValues
          argumentsInvoked.contains(supportedTagInfo)
```

mustBe true

But `argumentsInvoked` type is `List[Nothing]` instead of `List[SupportedTag]`

Comment: Mockito does check argument values. The issue must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: You are are no using correctly verify in order to catch the var, you can improve a little bit the code, am show a more specific what you need, i thing that you can try with argument captor but i cant get what are your var mocks or the structure of your code

Comment: @MarcoPens - Thanks. I have added the full spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to also specify the type of argument

```
val argumentCaptor1 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[DistributedTransaction])
      val argumentCaptor2 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass[SupportedTag,SupportedTag](classOf[SupportedTag]) //Note two types. First is type of argument, second is type of class. They are the same in my case. 
      val argumentCaptor3 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[MutationCondition])

      verify(servicesTestEnv.mockSupportedTagsTransactionRepository ,times(1))
        .add(argumentCaptor1.capture(),argumentCaptor2.capture(),argumentCaptor3.capture())
      val argumentsInvoked = argumentCaptor2.getAllValues //this now returns List[SupportedTag]
      argumentsInvoked.size mustBe 1
      val argument = argumentsInvoked.get(0)
      argument.course mustBe supportedTagInfo.course
      argument.subject mustBe supportedTagInfo.subject
      argument.topic mustBe supportedTagInfo.topic
```